# DropDownList Change() doesn't seem to fire

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So, I have been bashing my head against the desk for a day now. I know this may be a simple question, but the answer is eluding me. Help?

I have a DropDownList on a modal that is built from a partial view. I need to handle the .Change() on the DropDownList, pass the selected text from the DropDownList to a method in the controller that will then give me data to use in a ListBox.  Below are the code snippets that my research led me to.

all other controls on the modal function perfectly.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong or maybe point me in the right direction?

### ProcessController

```
// I have tried with [HttpGet], [HttpPost], and no attribute
public ActionResult RegionFilter(string regionName)
{
    // Breakpoint here is never hit
    var data = new List<object>();
    var result = new JsonResult();
    var vm = new PropertyModel();
    vm.getProperties();

    var propFilter = (from p in vm.Properties
                      where p.Region == regionName && p.Class == "Comparable"
                      select p).ToList();

    var listItems = propFilter.ToDictionary(prop => prop.Id, prop => prop.Name);

    data.Add(listItems);
    result.Data = data;
    return result;
}
```

### Razor View

```
@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ui_PropertyList.js")
}

...

<div id="wrapper1">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        ...

        <div id="fancyboxproperties" class="content">
            @Html.Partial("PropertyList", Model)
        </div>

        ...

        <input type="submit" name="bt_Submit" value="@ViewBag.Title" class="button" />
    }
</div>
```

### Razor (Partial View "PropertyList.cshtml")

```
... 

@{ var regions = (from r in Model.Properties
                select r.Region).Distinct(); }
<div>
    <label>Region Filter: </label>
    <select id="ddl_Region" name="ddl_Region">
        @foreach (var region in regions)
        {
            <option value=@region>@region</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>

// ListBox that needs to update after region is selected
<div> 
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.Properties, Model.Properties.Where(p => p.Class == "Comparable")
        .Select(p => new SelectListItem { Text = p.Name, Value = p.Id }),
        new { Multiple = "multiple", Id = "lb_C" })
</div>

...
```

### JavaScript (ui_PropertyList.js)

```
$(function () {

    // other events that work perfectly
    ...

    $("#ddl_Region").change(function () {
            $.getJSON("/Process/RegionFilter/" + $("#ddl_Region > option:selected").attr("text"), updateProperties(data));
        });
});

function updateProperties(data, status) {
    $("#lb_C").html("");
    for (var d in data) {
        var addOption = new Option(data[d].Value, data[d].Name);
        addOption.appendTo("#lb_C");
    }
}
```

Comment: I will just make a commentary: If you were using the `DropDownListFor Helper` you would need to use `Multiple = "multiple"`. But you aren't, so you don't need it. It's a redundance, `ListBox Helper` is already able to accept multiple values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback function passed to your `$.getJSON` method is wrong. You need to pass a *reference* to the function, not to invoke it.

Try this:

```
$.getJSON("/Process/RegionFilter/" + $("#ddl_Region > option:selected").text(), updateProperties);
```

Also, in order to get the text of the selected drop-down option, you need to use the `text()` function:

```
$("#ddl_Region > option:selected").text()
```

See [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: Yep - pretty sure data is the ajax response, in which case this is the best solution.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80215/discussion-on-answer-by-haim770-dropdownlist-change-doesnt-seem-to-fire).